# Consulta de múltiplas colunas SQL - Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, angular

Galera, estou tentando fazer uma consulta, onde tenho vários campos para realizar esta busca, podendo vir algum campo null. Estou usando o Laravel com Angular, não sei se dá pra fazer essa consulta no front mesmo, queria deixar essa responsabilidade para o angular mesmo. Se não poder, como posso fazer as cláusulas de consulta, SQL mesmo ou pela query do Laravel.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei fazer uma consulta simples para testar usando AND ou OR

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu colocar uma condição com OR, claro que ele irá atender uma das condições se for verdade, ele traz o resultado da primeira condição

Mas eu preciso que neste caso, se os campos não estiverem nullos, ele possa trazer o resultado das 2 condições, ai quando eu tento colocar AND, ele traz o resultado

Se vier um campo null da view, ele não mostra o resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso fazer uma consulta com todos aqueles campos na view, sabendo que pode vir algum campo NULL ?

Comment: No lugar de `os.status = NULL` utilize `os.status IS NULL`, afinal NULL é uma ausência de valores e portanto não pode ser comparada com o operador de igualdade.

Comment: Eu deixei == NULL ali como exemplo de que pode vir campos NULL da view, mas, desta forma ect * 
 from order_services as os
  where os.hierarchy = 'Comum' 
   and os.status = 'Provisório'; ele apresenta resultado

Comment: Estude mais detalhadamente o conceito de NULL e porque é necessário utilizar `IS NULL` / `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Achei que vc ter a mesma situação com a query do laravel, mas, ela me atendeu, adicionei vários wheres e resolvido

ex:
->where('tabela.campo1', $request->campo1)
->where('tabela.campo2', $request->campo2)
.
.
.
.